# What is wrong with check / uncheck All buttons?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am doing the Wes Bos 30 days Javascript course and on one optional feature, I need to add the three buttons on the bottom to: Clear all, Check all and uncheck All. 
This is the code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>LocalStorage</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!--
          Fish SVG Cred:
          https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=fish&i=589236
       -->

       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><g><path d="M495.9,425.3H16.1c-5.2,0-10.1,2.9-12.5,7.6c-2.4,4.7-2.1,10.3,0.9,14.6l39,56.4c2.6,3.8,7,6.1,11.6,6.1h401.7   c4.6,0,9-2.3,11.6-6.1l39-56.4c3-4.3,3.3-9.9,0.9-14.6C506,428.2,501.1,425.3,495.9,425.3z M449.4,481.8H62.6L43,453.6H469   L449.4,481.8z"/><path d="M158.3,122c7.8,0,14.1-6.3,14.1-14.1V43.4c0-7.8-6.3-14.1-14.1-14.1c-7.8,0-14.1,6.3-14.1,14.1v64.5   C144.2,115.7,150.5,122,158.3,122z"/><path d="M245.1,94.7c7.8,0,14.1-6.3,14.1-14.1V16.1c0-7.8-6.3-14.1-14.1-14.1C237.3,2,231,8.3,231,16.1v64.5   C231,88.4,237.3,94.7,245.1,94.7z"/><path d="M331.9,122c7.8,0,14.1-6.3,14.1-14.1V43.4c0-7.8-6.3-14.1-14.1-14.1s-14.1,6.3-14.1,14.1v64.5   C317.8,115.7,324.1,122,331.9,122z"/><path d="M9.6,385.2c5.3,2.8,11.8,1.9,16.2-2.2l50.6-47.7c56.7,46.5,126.6,71.9,198.3,71.9c0,0,0,0,0,0   c87.5,0,169.7-36.6,231.4-103.2c5-5.4,5-13.8,0-19.2c-61.8-66.5-144-103.2-231.4-103.2c-72,0-142.2,25.6-199,72.5l-50-47.1   c-4.4-4.1-10.9-5-16.2-2.2c-5.3,2.8-8.3,8.7-7.4,14.6l11.6,75L2.2,370.6C1.3,376.5,4.2,382.4,9.6,385.2z M380.9,230.8   c34.9,14.3,67.2,35.7,95.3,63.6c-10.1,10-20.8,19.2-31.9,27.5c-22.4-3.3-29.6-8.8-30.7-9.7c-4-5.7-11.8-7.7-18.1-4.4   c-6.9,3.6-9.5,12.2-5.9,19.1c1.9,3.5,7.3,10.3,22.4,16c-10.1,5.7-20.5,10.7-31.1,15.1C352.4,320.2,352.4,268.6,380.9,230.8z    M36.3,255.6l29.4,27.7c5.3,5,13.6,5.1,19.1,0.3c53.2-47.6,120.7-73.7,190-73.7c26.9,0,53.2,3.9,78.5,11.3   c-29.3,44.6-29.3,102,0,146.6c-25.3,7.4-51.6,11.3-78.5,11.3c-69,0-136.3-26-189.4-73.2c-2.7-2.4-13.4-6.3-19.1,0.3l-30.1,28.3   l5.7-40C42.2,293,36.3,255.6,36.3,255.6z"/><circle cx="398.8" cy="273.8" r="14.1"/></g></svg>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>LOCAL TAPAS</h2>
        <p></p>
        <ul class="plates">
          <li>Loading Tapas...</li>
        </ul>
        <form class="add-items">
          <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Name" required>
          <input type="submit" value="+ Add Item">
          <hr />
          <button type="button" name="clearAll">Clear all</button>
          <button type="button" name="checkThemAll">Check all</button>
          <button type="button" name="uncheckThemAll">Uncheck all</button>


        </form>
      </div>

    <script>
      const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items');
      const itemsList = document.querySelector('.plates');
      const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[type=button]')

      function addItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const text = (this.querySelector('[name=item]')).value
        const item = {
          text,
          done: false
        }
        items.push(item);
        populateList(items, itemsList)
        this.reset();
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items))
      }

      function populateList(plates = [], platesList){

        platesList.innerHTML = plates.map((plate, i) => {
          return `
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-index=${i} id="item${i}" ${plate.done ? 'checked' : null} />
            <label for="item${i}">${plate.text}</label>  
          </li>
          `
        }).join('');
      }

      function toggleDone(e){
        if (!e.target.matches('input')) return; 
        const el = e.target;
        const index = el.dataset.index;
        items[index].done = !items[index].done;
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
        populateList(items, itemsList);
      }

      function clearOptions() {
        if (this.name === "clearAll"){
          localStorage.removeItem('items');
          items.splice(0, items.length)

        } else if( this.name === "checkThemAll"){
          items.map(item => {
            item.done = "true";
          })
          localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));

        } else if (this.name === "uncheckThemAll"){
          items.map(item => {
            item.done = "false";
          })
          localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
        } else return;

        populateList(items, itemsList)
        console.table("ITEMS", items)
        console.table("LOCALSTORAGE", localStorage)
      }

      addItems.addEventListener('submit', addItem);
      itemsList.addEventListener('click', toggleDone);
      buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', clearOptions));

      populateList(items, itemsList);
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

I would appreaciate if someone can tell me why my checkAll and uncheckAll buttons are not working properly. They both check all, but not uncheck any. Items and Localstorage seem be working right when I console.log them.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you also provided an online playground with the reproduction of this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using strings, instead of booleans:

`item.done = "false"`

Should be:

`item.done = false`

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/0j5m91p4/

Because you were using a string, it was a truthy value, therefore it would evaluate to `true`.